# How to monitor resources used by scroll API for each scroll Id? what happens when clearScroll Api is called

Tags: elasticsearch

How to monitor memory resources or search contexts used by scroll API for each scroll Id? where does these search contexts are stored, is there a way to see or monitor them? what does the parameter keepAlive mean for the java api public SearchRequest scroll(TimeValue keepAlive) {...}

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.5/java-rest-high-clear-scroll.html#java-rest-high-clear-scroll-async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check how many search contexts are currently opened by calling the [Node stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html) but there's no way (that I know of) to see how much memory is used by them:

```
GET _nodes/stats/indices?filter_path=**.open_contexts
```

=>

```
{
  "nodes" : {
    "QjjWj45NQkGC9qcaylDDVQ" : {
      "indices" : {
        "search" : {
          "open_contexts" : 0
        }
      }
    },
    "eZbpkckXSxSxzD8c_QOkEA" : {
      "indices" : {
        "search" : {
          "open_contexts" : 3
        }
      }
    },
    "0VFJaC2uTraudPCMqODhiw" : {
      "indices" : {
        "search" : {
          "open_contexts" : 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The search contexts are stored on the heap.

Furthermore, the `keepAlive` parameter tells how long the context stays available in memory before being cleared automatically.

Comment: in the node stats Api , 
"search": {
"open_contexts": 15,
"query_total": 52511,
"query_time_in_millis": 1588864,
"query_current": 0,
"fetch_total": 46521,
"fetch_time_in_millis": 326210,
"fetch_current": 0,
"scroll_total": 1110,
"scroll_time_in_millis": 3928255092,
"scroll_current": 530,
"suggest_total": 0,
"suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
"suggest_current": 0}, what does scroll_current indicate?

Comment: The answer to that question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54887206/in-node-stats-api-what-does-scroll-parameters-indicate/54887380#54887380