# In Node Stats Api what does scroll parameters indicate?

Tags: elasticsearch

In the [Node stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html) (_nodes/stats/indices) the response for an index has following search body, "search": { "open_contexts": 15, "query_total": 52511, "query_time_in_millis": 1588864, "query_current": 0, "fetch_total": 46521, "fetch_time_in_millis": 326210, "fetch_current": 0, "scroll_total": 1110, "scroll_time_in_millis": 3928255092, "scroll_current": 530, "suggest_total": 0, "suggest_time_in_millis": 0, "suggest_current": 0}, what does scroll parameters(scroll_total, scroll_time_in_millis, scroll_current) indicate here?

Comment: Odd that they don't both contain this information, but it looks like this page has more information on these parameters than the Node stats API doc linked https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-nodes.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `scroll_current` indicates the number of scroll contexts currently open
- `scroll_total` indicates the number of scroll contexts that have been completed since the node last restarted
- `scroll_time_in_millis` indicates the time that scroll contexts have been held open since the node last restarted

Comment: Then how come scroll_current is greater than open_contexts ?

Comment: a scroll context is different than a search context. One search context (i.e. `open_context`) = N scroll contexts (i.e. `scroll_current`). One scroll search is composed of several scroll requests, one for each batch of data.

Comment: Yes, it's also described on that page