# Is it possible to retrieve information on all active scroll contexts from Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm interested in monitoring how many concurrent scroll contexts are open on a given Elasticsearch cluster. Since they are stateful, it seems reasonable that it may be able to retrieve a list. Nothing in `/_cat` looks relevant though. Is this possible?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54886567/4604579

Comment: Yes thanks @Val this very useful. I think that makes this question a dupe.